# Unable to add image as Launchscreen which is compatible with all the iPhones

Tags: ios, launchimage, uilaunchimagefile

I have added an image to `UIImageView` in my `LaunchScreen.xib` file and made it aspect fit the screen of the device. I've added *image.png*, *image@2x.png* and *image@3x.png* but *iPhone 4/4s, 5/5s and 6* all are using *image@2x.png* which leaves borders outside the image.

How do I specify which image to use to make it fit every device screen?

Comment: Are you using autolayout to pin the imageview to the edges of the launch screen? Also, try using aspect fill in stead of aspect fit

Comment: Yes, I **am** using auto-layout to pin the imageView to the edges. But if I use the aspect fill then it doesn't look like a seamless transition from my LaunchImage to the image in my _initial view controller_.

Comment: could you upload a screenshot of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 8 and above you don't need to add conditions for iPhone or iPad. you can set a one image for all type of platform using size classes.

Just use size classes and set your image to view. it will look better for all iphones and ipads.

This is a comment from apple : -

Size classes. Size classes for iOS 8 enable designing a single universal storyboard with customized layouts for both iPhone and iPad. With size classes you can define common views and constraints once, and then add variations for each supported form factor. iOS Simulator and asset catalogs fully support size classes as well.

Comment: But I need to support iOS 7 as well. Also, there is no distinct size-class for 3.5 inch screens (i.e. iPhone 4/4s).

Answer (score 0):

**you can use Images assets add launch images for all iphone and ipad sizes**